# Derivation in Evans not reproducible

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

I am currently reading in Evans where he discusses the Euler-Poisson equation on page 81.

There we have that $\displaystyle \partial_rU(x;r,t)=\frac{r}{n\alpha(n)r^n}\int_{B(x,r)}\Delta u(y,t)\mathrm{d}y$

Now he makes another derivative which is not reproducible for me

$\displaystyle \partial_{rr}U(x;r,t)=\frac{1}{\alpha(n)r^{n-1}n}\int_{\partial B(x,r)}\Delta u\mathrm{d}S+\left ( \frac{1}{n}-1\right ) \frac{1}{\alpha(n)r^n}\int_{B(x,r)}\Delta u \mathrm{d}y$

where $\alpha(n)$ is the volume of the n-th unit sphere. How is this derivative obtained?

Comment: The question seems to be "How do we differentiate the first expression with respect to $r$ to get the second expression?"

Comment: @ZacharySelk Made an edit.

Comment: You've written the initial integral incorrectly. It should be $$\partial_r U(x;r,t) = \frac{1}{r^{n-1}n \alpha(n)} \int_{B(x,r)} \Delta u(y,t) \, dy.$$

Comment: @UmbertoP. I corrected this. But I think since it is the integral over the ball, it should be $r^n$ not $r^{n-1}$.

Comment: But there was an $r$ in the numerator to begin with. Your edit agrees with the formula in the comment